# DataTransformer get error "undefined call method getName"

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I'm a weird problem that I do not know how to solve.
I created a datatransformer, which among other things in my other projects, works perfectly, but when I start the page I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method 
Acme\CoreBundle\Transformer\HiddenToIdTransformer::getName() in
/var/www/Acme/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionExtension.php line 49
```

Here the code:

**transformer**

```
class HiddenToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $class;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function transform($entity)
    {
        if (null === $entity) {
            return;
        }

        return $entity->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($name)
    {
        if (!$name) {
            return null;
        }

        $entity = $this->objectManager
            ->getRepository('AcmeCoreBundle:Locality')
            ->findOneByLocality($name);

        if (null === $entity) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException();
        }

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

**type**

```
class EntityHiddenType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new HiddenToIdTransformer($this->objectManager);
        $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => null,
            'invalid_message' => 'The entity does not exist.',
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'hidden';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'entity_hidden';
    }
}
```

**services**

```
<service id="datatransformer.entity_hidden" class="Acme\CoreBundle\Transformer\HiddenToIdTransformer">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="entity_hidden" />
</service>
```

And in this way recall the transformer:

```
->add('locality', 'entity_hidden')
```

I do not understand what is wrong, I repeat that in my other projects, the exact same code works fine!

Maybe it's a bug in 2.3.7 incurred?

Comment: btw. you are currently not using the entity-manager in your form-type => consider removing the dependency :) my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured the class of the `Transformer` as a service tagged with `form.type` instead of the form-type's class:

```
<service 
    id="datatransformer.entity_hidden"  
    class="Acme\CoreBundle\Transformer\HiddenToIdTransformer" <!-- <= HERE -->
>
```

The form-type's service definition should be like this:

```
<service id="form.type.entity_hidden" class="Acme\CoreBundle\Form\Type\EntityHiddenType">
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        <tag name="form.type" alias="entity_hidden" />
</service>
```

If you want your data-transformer to be a service aswell ... don't tag it with `form.type` otherwise symfony will try to call it's `getName()` method which doesn't exist.

Remove the tag ...

```
<tag name="form.type" alias="entity_hidden" />
```

... and the exception will disappear.

Comment: nifr really many thanks!
I was going crazy for a mistake so stupid!